# Custom Object Look up Field Permission

Tags: custom-permission

I have two custom object `Facility__c` and `Groupage__c`. **Facility** is parent and **Groupage** is child. So, **Groupage** object look up field `Facility__C`. On a VF page, I am not able to see `Facility__c` field of `Groupage__c` object in prod while same thing is running fine in Sandbox.

I have check every field permission of **Groupage** and **Facility** object on profile and in field accessibility permission. But still Facility field is not showing up on page. I have used `<apex:inputField>` in class. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: did you set the Field Level Security correctly?... Check once by going to the Particular Field and check by clicking "Set Field-Level Security" button.

Comment: Yeah, already done that but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are few possibilities:
1. Profile permission to object.
2. Field level security and Field level Accessibility.
3. Object Permission to User.
4. Have you added the field to the standard page Layout?

Please look into these if this resolves your issue.

Thanks,
Vipul

Answer (score 0):

Check the Field Visibility in the Prod.
This may be solve your issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the object Deployment Status. Is it :-
1. In Development
2. Deployed

It should be deployed then only it will be visible.

Comment: thx for the help...